# Cannot connect to Redis installed on VirtualBox running Ubuntu from Windows 10

Tags: c#, redis, virtualbox, servicestack.redis

I've setup an Ubuntu image on VirtualBox on a Windows 10 host. On the Ubuntu guest I've installed Redis which runs on port 6379 (TCP) by default.

I tried to follow the tutorial from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXQRqek3kLw but i get a "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6379".

I've setup port forwarding using virtualbox and setting redis.conf.

What should I do?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is you (Windows host). Your Ubuntu is running in a different network.

Comment: Make sure port 6379 is open on the firewall.